# Need clarification in passing an Array to a method

Tags: arrays, reference

```
public class ABC {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i[] = {1};
        change_i(i);
        System.out.println(i[0]);   //prints 1
    }
    public static void change_i(int a[]) {
        int j[]={3};
        a=j;
    }
}

public class ABC {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i[] = {1};
        change_i(i);
        System.out.println(i[0]);   //prints 3
    }
    public static void change_i(int a[]) {
        int j[]={3};
        a[0]=j[0];
    }
}
```

What's the difference actually in these two assignments  `a=j;` and  `a[0]=j[0];` Why does the output differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `a=j`

Makes the variable `a` reference whatever variable `j` is referencing. Meaning, after the statement is executed, **`a` and `j` reference the same thing.**

2) `a[0]=j[0]`

Makes the value of the first element (at index 0) of array `a` have the value of the first element of array `j`. Meaning, after the statement is executed, **the first element of `a` and `j` reference the same thing**

**EDIT**

As far as specifically to your question, within the method `change_i`, the following happens for each statement:

1)

```
public static void change_i(int a[]) {  // pass the array a by value
    int j[]={3};                        // create a new array of integers with size 1 that holds the number 3 as its only element
    a=j;                                // make this passed copy value of array a now point to j
}
```

Java passes everything by value ([Look here for detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/3928341)) so after the method `change_i` is executed, nothing changes. The reason is that variable `a` inside `change_i` method serves as a **reference** to the array `a` that was passed into the method. After you execute the statement `a=j`, this variable `a` now references the array `j` that was created inside the method however nothing affects the array that passed in. Only thing that changes is **what `a`, within `changes_i`, references**

2)

```
public static void change_i(int a[]) {  // pass the array a by value
    int j[]={3};                        // create a new array of integers with size 1 that holds the number 3 as its only element
    a[0]=j[0];                          // used the copy value of array a to access the first element of original array a and give it the value of the first element of array j, which is 3
}
```

This method actually alters the array that was passed in. Since the variable `a` inside this method references the array that was passed in, when we call `a[0]`, we are using this copied reference to access the first element of the original array and thus `a[0]=j[0]` actually alters the array.

You should read more about [how Java passes values into methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Comment: So does it mean that in a=j if the value of array j changes value of array a also changes??

Comment: @PraveenKumar look at my edit for more detail. As far as this specific question, `a` and `j` are just two different variables that reference the **same array** so the answer would be yes. However, you need to understand that there are no array `a` and array `j`, the are both one array with `a` and `j` being referential variables to the array.